# Is there a way to make incremental backups of an Android phone — without using ClockworkMod Recovery, and without buying any paid app?

Tags: android, backup

## Background information

I own an aging Samsung smartphone with Android and with 8 GB of built-in flash memory.  I've installed an aftermarket case, wrestled it off, bought a 32 GB MicroSD card, installed the card, and put the case back on.

It would be convenient to be able to keep a dozen or so old backups of my device on the MicroSD card, without the mild annoyance of having to use [MTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Transfer_Protocol) to move some of the older backups onto a computer.

In order to do this, I'd have to make incremental backups.  One way to do so would be to use a [custom recovery image](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/All_About_Recovery_Images) which supports making such backups.

Recent versions of [ClockworkMod Recovery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClockworkMod_Recovery), one popular Android custom recovery image, allow users to create incremental backups.  ClockworkMod Recovery calls such backups ["dedupe" or "dup" backups](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120359/clockworkmod-recovery-supports-three-backup-formats-whats-the-difference-betwe).  True, I hear that [such backups are slow](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120359/clockworkmod-recovery-supports-three-backup-formats-whats-the-difference-betwe), but I have time.

I've tried the latest prebuilt version of ClockworkMod Recovery available for my phone:  v6.0.4.5.  It seems buggy.  I would rather not rely upon it for something important as backups.

Luckily, there exist [other custom recovery images](https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/All_About_Recovery_Images), as well as other Android apps.

## My question

Does any recovery image other than ClockworkMod Recovery, or any app, allow me to make incremental backups of a phone's `/system` and `/data` partitions?

Please assume that my phone is rooted, but that would much rather not pay money to buy commercial backup tools or commercial recovery images.

If the answer is "no, it's impossible", please post your answer as a "comment".  Or, if you post it as an "answer", please name some tools you've tried which lack support for incremental backups.

## My criteria, ranked in order

So, in order from most important to least important, I'm looking for:

1. A piece of software which can make incremental backups of an Android phone.
2. Preferably available at no cost.
3. And, if it's open-source, that's even better.
4. If it's still maintained and there's an active developer who still responds to bug reports, then that's a bonus.